# Trying to use OQS-OpenSSL_1_1_1 in Golang

Tags: c, go, cryptography, csr, post-quantum-cryptography

I'm use open-quantum-safe/openssl to create certificates and key pairs , now i want to use this library(https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/openssl) to create certs & keys using golang so i can create api that uses openssl to create certs & key...etc. So what i'm asking is what is the best way to do so which is using OQS-OpenSSL_1_1_1 in golang.

i didn't try much because I'm not sure what to try but i have two idea one is to create a Go binding not sure how to though , and the second in theory i should be able to use C library in Golang but i don't think that OQS-OpenSSL_1_1_1 is a typical C library to just use. so if any experts can guide me to the right direction.